# Return Array for Maximum Sum

Tags: arrays, dynamic, sum, partition

I have trouble to find a solution for the following question.
"Given an integer array A, you partition the array in (contiguous) subarrays of length at most k.  After partitioning, each subarray has their values changed to become the maximum value of the subarray.

These subarrays will be used to create a new array in the order when they are partitioned.  The sum of the new array should have the maximum value.

Example:
Input: A = [1, 15, 7, 9, 2, 5, 10], k = 3

Output: newArray = [15, 15, 15, 9, 10, 10, 10]

One possible solution is to try all possible partitions and find the max sum.  But I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A posible implementation is to create a dictionary that stores the first value in the partition and if the next value is greater than the one stored, get rid of the one in the dictionary until the end of the partition. And repeat this for all partitions.